# Transaction dropped and replaced but still shows as pending in etherscan

Tags: transactions, metamask, pending-transactions

I canceled a transaction by sending another 0 ETH transaction to myself customizing the nonce in Metamask. Now the canceled transaction shows as "dropped & replaced" in etherscan, but it's still pending:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xde32215b3628d7b5e690194464898e4d187c2592d439e143d403d28ddeb6224e

If I try to send a transaction with a higher nonce it will not pass through as there is a pending transaction with a lower nonce. If I try to send another transaction with the same nonce as the canceled one, I get an "rpc error with payload" from Metamask. So basically my wallet is stuck. Is there something I can do about it?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new transaction has been marked « success » by Etherscan (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfa14e402325f30b24add5d897cb801d31486669f6d48f14348b6844955946a03).

The network is currently overloaded so your transactions may take longer to proceed, according to the allocated gas price.

You can follow the average gas price here : https://ethgasstation.info/.

Answer (score -1):

Jesus

Tried to sent USDT to spot exchange it dropped. So ethereum scam decided to charge me for one more transaction.

First transaction

0x84e97cadf95bc37f178a36f5acb7f38248cc41dc5eba347c2787691cd2bf60bc THIS TRANSACTION WAS CHARGED 8.8 USD

replaced with

0xcea7cc616212da28d839bfa04ee6e4456ba076edd6df1386709343a0483e6d0d and charged 10.63

Ethereum scam NOT ONLY took my founds but took all my ETHEREUM for gas.

Dont use this scam or you will lose your money. Mine is gone.